# HTML5 Application Cache not working in ie8+ so need its alternatives for ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, html5-appcache

HTML5 Application Cache not working in ie8+, so i need some of the solution which makes my resource available even in offline mode in ie8+ browsers, in all other browsers the html5 appcache is working fine, only had problem with ie, so need solution for ie8+.

Comment: Of course it's not working in IE8, it's not a HTML5 capable browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ian, but i know it and it is not supported in ie9 even and will be supproted in ie10. thats why i need some of the alternative for the same.

Comment: Fair enough, but I also added an answer below, which may or may not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ie 8 and all 8+ versions does not support html5 offline cache, and even 9 does not support this but recently 10 has a developer document which has this support.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [Researching HTML5 Offline](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/08/16/researching-html5-offline/). They suggest Google Gears, even though it's deprecated (post is from August 2010).